# php preg_replace with empty string replacement character does not work on non printable characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to remove non printable characters in a string, except some characters that I need.

```
$arr = ['Ù', 'é', '€'];
$string = "é & Ù @ ♣ ☂ % & € À";
$acceptedChars = implode('\\', $arr);
$string = preg_replace('/[^[:print:] ' . $acceptedChars . ']/', '', $string);

echo 'Test : ' . $string;
```

My issue is that instead of replacing the unwanted characters by an empty string as set in the second parameter, I get this instead :

[image]

Comment: You missed `/u` modifier. `'/[^[:print:] ' . $acceptedChars . ']/u'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does not seem to do what I want in this case, it just makes the icons appear correctly, but what I want is the non printable symbols to disappear (replaced by an empty string)

Comment: Do you mean  you want `preg_replace('/[^ -~' . $acceptedChars . ']/u', '', $string);`? Remove all chars other than printable ASCII chars and `$acceptedChars`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This actually solves my issue, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all chars other than printable ASCII chars and `$acceptedChars` you
can use

```php
$string = preg_replace('/[^ -~' . $acceptedChars . ']/u', '', $string);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/qcZme).

The  `-~` pattern is a known pattern to match any printable ASCII chars.

The `u` modifier is necessary to make the regex work with Unicode strings.

Comment: I found out that there are some characters (I havent been able to detect which exactly) that break the csv export with this regex, while the one with [:print:] does not break but removes all characters with accents (é, à , Û....). What does [:print:] removes more than -~ ?? I need a combination of both so that i can remove the character that break my csv but allow me to keep the characters with accents (from custom array of characters)

Comment: @naspy971 I believe you have one of ``^\-]/`` there. so, you need `$string = preg_replace('/[^ -~' . preg_quote($acceptedChars, '/') . ']/u', '', $string);`. Or, using `[:print:]`, `preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/u', '', $string)`

Comment: That solves my issue, thanks ! but one last question what kind  of symbols are contained by **^\-]/**  ? the one that could break a csv export ?

Comment: @naspy971 ``^``, ``\``, `-` and `]` are the symbols that must be escaped inside a character class and `/` must be escaped since it is used as a regex delimiter.